# Codeigniter select most recent record in Group By

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, group-by

How do I tell codeigniter to select the most recent row when grouping, either by a timestamp or the id.
Currently it is retuning the oldest one.
I am creating an activity feed and grouping similar activities, however the most recent post is the one I am wanting to display, not the first one.

```
public function get_activity_notifications($users, $collections, $interests){
    $this->db->from($this->notifications_table);
    $this->db->where_in('data3', $interests);
    $this->db->where_in('type', 'post');

    $this->db->or_where_in('data', $collections);
    $type_array = array('Replied','Commented', 'ending_soon');

    $this->db->where_in('type', $type_array);
    $this->db->or_where_in('instigator_id', $users);
    $this->db->order_by("added", "desc"); 


    $this->db->group_by(array("data3", "type")); 

    $query = $this->db->get();
    print_r($this->db->last_query());
    return $query->result_array();



}
```

Comment: $this->db->order_by("added", "desc"); is the correct one you are using it already

Comment: That orders the results coming back from the database, but doesn't mean that the most recent row from the orderby is selected

Comment: Try adding order_by after group_by